# importError with pyinstaller using Twisted

Tags: python, twisted, pyinstaller

I tried to compile my python work with pyinstaller, with command:

```
pyinstaller.py -F zchat_server.py
```

and got error msg:

F:\workplace\Python\network-study\zchat\dist>zchat_server.exe

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
  File "D:\pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller\loader\iu.py", line 386, in importHook
    mod = _self_doimport(nm, ctx, fqname)
  File "D:\pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller\loader\iu.py", line 480, in doimport
    exec co in mod.__dict__
  File "F:\workplace\Python\network-study\zchat\build\pyi.win32\zchat_server\out
00-PYZ.pyz\twisted", line 53, in <module>
  File "F:\workplace\Python\network-study\zchat\build\pyi.win32\zchat_server\out
00-PYZ.pyz\twisted", line 37, in _checkRequirements
ImportError: Twisted requires zope.interface 3.6.0 or later: no module named zop
e.interface.
```

I'm new in this, I compile my zchat_view.py (using wxPython), it works just fine.
But with Twisted, I'm confused. Hope for solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some research on this - it seems like there are problems with PyInstaller and Zope.

Here are some reference links:

[Problems finding module Zope](http://www.pyinstaller.org/ticket/615)

[PyInstaller fails to find module Zope](http://www.pyinstaller.org/ticket/502) - This link also speaks of a potential solution.

[Pyinstaller can't handle namespace packages correctly, such as zope.interface](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pyinstaller/POYwzd-VrHU).

Hopefully, these help you to identify a workaround for this bug in PyInstaller.

To answer Glyph's query - You can define additional dependencies for PyInstaller by editing the spec files generated by running the PyInstaller command

Comment: thinks a lot! I'v generate the spec file using pyinstaller, and add dependency to it by looking up to it's documents, but the problem stills, I think I'll just try another utilty to make it work. Still think for your help.

Comment: @Prahalad - Thanks for the research - although it makes me want to ask you to do some more to fill out this answer :-).  Were you able to find any workaround?

Comment: The workaround is in the second link. Add `__init__.py` to the zope folder in `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\zope`

Answer (score 0):

`zope.interface` is a dependency of Twisted.  Does pyinstaller have a configuration file somewhere where you need to declare that dependency?

Comment: I add the dependency and the problem stills. I'll try another solution, think you.

Answer (score 0):

I think package **python-zope-interface** maybe helpful for you:

```
yum install python-zope-interface
```

if it show:

```
Package python-zope-interface-4.0.5-1.fc19.x86_64 already installed
and latest version
```

run:

```
yum erase python-zope-interface
yum install python-zope-interface
```

I tried and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I've added --hidden-import=twisted to the pyinstaller command and everything worked well.

```
pyinstaller --hidden-import=twisted
```